# how to use SVM to classify if the shape of features for each sample is matrix? Is it simply to reshape the matrix to long vector?

Tags: python, svm

I have 120 samples and the shape of features for each sample is matrix of 15*17. how to use SVM to classify? Is it simply to reshape the matrix to long vector?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be the approach I would recommend. It is essentially the same procedure that is used when utilizing images in image classification tasks, since each image can be seen as a matrix. 
So what people do is to write the matrix as a long vector, consisting of every column concatenated to one another.
So you can do the same here.